How to insert a chart in powerpoint using openxml and c# without making the ppt corrupted?
I have tried this code here that produces chart in powerpoint file but makes the file corrupted and gives the repair message. I wanted the code to generate a uncorrupted powerpoint file with the chart inside. Here is the code I have tried so far -
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using P = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using C = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts;
using P14 = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.PowerPoint;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

string[] headers = { "", "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3" };

CreatePresentation();
void CreatePresentation()
{
string filepath = "C:\\Testing\\Template_Creation\\newTest2\\NewFolder\\file.pptx";

// Create a presentation at a specified file path. The presentation document type is pptx, by default.
PresentationDocument presentationDoc = PresentationDocument.Create(filepath, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);
PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDoc.AddPresentationPart();
presentationPart.Presentation = new Presentation();

CreatePresentationParts(presentationPart);

//Dispose the presentation handle
presentationDoc.Dispose();
}

void CreatePresentationParts(PresentationPart presentationPart)
{
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student("TESTNAME00", new List<int> { 33, 44, 23 }),
        new Student("TESTNAME01", new List<int> { 33, 34, 33 }),
        new Student("TESTNAME02", new List<int> { 33, 34, 33 }),
        new Student("TESTNAME03", new List<int> { 33, 44, 23 }),
    };

SlideMasterIdList slideMasterIdList1 = new SlideMasterIdList(new SlideMasterId() { Id = (UInt32Value)2147483648U, RelationshipId = "rId1" });
SlideIdList slideIdList1 = new SlideIdList(new SlideId() { Id = (UInt32Value)256U, RelationshipId = "rId2" });
SlideSize slideSize1 = new SlideSize() { Cx = 9144000, Cy = 6858000, Type = SlideSizeValues.Screen4x3 };
NotesSize notesSize1 = new NotesSize() { Cx = 6858000, Cy = 9144000 };
DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle1 = new DefaultTextStyle();

presentationPart.Presentation.Append(slideMasterIdList1, slideIdList1, slideSize1, notesSize1, defaultTextStyle1);

SlidePart slidePart1;
SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart1;
SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart1;
ThemePart themePart1;

slidePart1 = CreateSlidePart(presentationPart);
slideLayoutPart1 = CreateSlideLayoutPart(slidePart1);
slideMasterPart1 = CreateSlideMasterPart(slideLayoutPart1);
themePart1 = CreateTheme(slideMasterPart1);

//this methods CreateSlidePart,CreateSlideLayoutPart and others sample code you will get from here - ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/presentation/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name?tabs=cs]). I could not add them due to code size limit.

slideMasterPart1.AddPart(slideLayoutPart1, "rId1");
presentationPart.AddPart(slideMasterPart1, "rId1");
presentationPart.AddPart(themePart1, "rId5");

ChartPart chartPart = slidePart1.AddNewPart<ChartPart>("rId2");
GenerateChart(chartPart, slidePart1, presentationPart, students);
}

void GenerateChart(ChartPart chartPart, SlidePart slidePart, PresentationPart presentationPart, List<Student> students)
{
    //Create a chart part in the slide part

chartPart.ChartSpace = new C.ChartSpace();
chartPart.ChartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
chartPart.ChartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
chartPart.ChartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
chartPart.ChartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c16r2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart");

chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new C.Date1904());

chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild(new C.EditingLanguage() { Val = "en-US" });
C.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild(new C.Chart());
chart.AppendChild(new C.AutoTitleDeleted() { Val = true });

// Create a plot area for the chart
C.PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild(new C.PlotArea());
C.Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild(new C.Layout());

//// Create a bar chart
C.BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild(new C.BarChart(
    new C.BarDirection() { Val = C.BarDirectionValues.Bar },
    new C.BarGrouping() { Val = C.BarGroupingValues.PercentStacked },
    new C.VaryColors() { Val = false },
    new GapWidth() { Val = 150 },
    new Overlap() { Val = 100 }
));

//// Create chart series
for (int i = 1; i < headers.Length; i++) // Skip the first column (Name)
{
    C.BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild(new C.BarChartSeries(
        new C.Index() { Val = (uint)i - 1 },
        new C.Order() { Val = (uint)i - 1 },
        new C.SeriesText(new C.NumericValue() { Text = headers[i] })
    ));

    // Add color to the series
    A.ShapeProperties chartShapeProperties = barChartSeries.AppendChild(new A.ShapeProperties());
    chartShapeProperties.AppendChild(new A.SolidFill(
        new A.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = GetColorHex(i - 1) }
    ));

    // Adding category axis to the chart
    C.CategoryAxisData categoryAxisData = barChartSeries.AppendChild(new C.CategoryAxisData());

    // Constructing the chart category
    C.StringReference stringReference = categoryAxisData.AppendChild(new C.StringReference());
    C.Formula formula = stringReference.AppendChild(new C.Formula("Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" + (students.Count + 1)));

    C.StringCache stringCache = stringReference.AppendChild(new C.StringCache());
    //stringCache.Append(new FormatCode("General"));
    stringCache.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value((uint)headers.Length) });

    for (int j = 0; j < students.Count; j++)
    {
        stringCache.AppendChild(new C.NumericPoint() { Index = (uint)j }).Append(new C.NumericValue(students[j].Name.ToString()));
    }

    // Adding values to the chart series
    C.Values values = barChartSeries.AppendChild(new C.Values());
    C.NumberReference numberReference = values.AppendChild(new C.NumberReference());
    //formula = numberReference.AppendChild(new C.Formula($"Sheet1!$" + GetExcelColumnName(i + 1) + "$2:$" + GetExcelColumnName(i + 1) + "$" + (students.Count + 1)));

    numberReference.AppendChild(new C.Formula($"Sheet1!$" + GetExcelColumnName(i + 1) + "$2:$" + GetExcelColumnName(i + 1) + "$" + (students.Count + 1)));
    C.NumberingCache numberingCache = numberReference.AppendChild(new C.NumberingCache());
    numberingCache.Append(new PointCount() { Val = (uint)students.Count });

    for (uint j = 0; j < students.Count; j++)
    {
        var value = students[(int)j].Values[i - 1];
        numberingCache.AppendChild(new C.NumericPoint() { Index = j }).Append(new C.NumericValue(value.ToString()));
        //numberingCache.AppendChild(new C.PointCount() { Val = (uint)j });
    }
}

barChart.AppendChild(new C.DataLabels(
    new C.ShowLegendKey() { Val = false },
    new C.ShowValue() { Val = true },
    new C.ShowCategoryName() { Val = false },
    new C.ShowSeriesName() { Val = false },
    new C.ShowPercent() { Val = false },
    new C.ShowBubbleSize() { Val = false },
    new C.DataLabelPosition() { Val = C.DataLabelPositionValues.Center },
    new ChartShapeProperties(new A.Outline(new NoFill(), new A.EffectList()))
));

barChart.Append(new C.AxisId() { Val = 48650112u });
barChart.Append(new C.AxisId() { Val = 48672768u });

//// Adding Category Axis
plotArea.AppendChild(
    new C.CategoryAxis(
        new C.AxisId() { Val = 48650112u },
        new C.Scaling(new C.Orientation() { Val = C.OrientationValues.MinMax }),
        new C.Delete() { Val = false },
        new C.AxisPosition() { Val = C.AxisPositionValues.Left },
        new C.TickLabelPosition() { Val = C.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo },
        new C.CrossingAxis() { Val = 48672768u },
        new C.AutoLabeled() { Val = true },
        new C.LabelAlignment() { Val = C.LabelAlignmentValues.Center },
        new C.MajorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.None },
        new C.MinorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.None },
        new C.ShapeProperties(
            new NoFill(),
            new A.Outline
            (
                new SolidFill()
            )
         )
     ));

// Adding Value Axis
plotArea.AppendChild(
   new C.ValueAxis(
       new C.AxisId() { Val = 48672768u },
       new C.Scaling(new C.Orientation() { Val = C.OrientationValues.MinMax }),
       new C.Delete() { Val = false },
       new C.AxisPosition() { Val = C.AxisPositionValues.Left },
       new C.MajorGridlines(),
       new C.NumberingFormat()
       {
           FormatCode = "0%",
           SourceLinked = true
       },
       new C.TickLabelPosition() { Val = C.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo },
       new C.CrossingAxis() { Val = 48650112u },
       new C.Crosses() { Val = C.CrossesValues.AutoZero },
       new C.CrossBetween() { Val = C.CrossBetweenValues.Between },
       new MajorGridlines(
       new C.ShapeProperties
       (
          new NoFill(),
          new A.Outline
          (
               new NoFill()
           ),
          new EffectList()
       ),
       new C.TextProperties
       (
           new BodyProperties(),
           new ListStyle(),
           new A.Paragraph
           (
               new A.ParagraphProperties
               (
                   new DefaultParagraphProperties
                   (
                        new SolidFill
                        (
                            new A.SchemeColor
                            (
                                new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 65000 },
                                new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 35000 }
                            )
                        )
                   )
               ),
               new EndParagraphRunProperties()
           )
       )
       ),
       new MajorTickMark(),
       new MinorTickMark()
     )
   );

chart.Append(
    new C.PlotVisibleOnly() { Val = true },
    new C.DisplayBlanksAs() { Val = C.DisplayBlanksAsValues.Gap },
    new C.ShowDataLabelsOverMaximum() { Val = false }
);

chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();

Slide slide1 = slidePart.Slide;
CommonSlideData commonSlideData1 = slide1.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
ShapeTree shapeTree1 = commonSlideData1.GetFirstChild<ShapeTree>();

P.GraphicFrame graphicFrame1 = shapeTree1.AppendChild(new P.GraphicFrame());

P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties nonVisualGroupShapeProperties1 = shapeTree1.AppendChild(new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties());
nonVisualGroupShapeProperties1.NonVisualDrawingProperties = new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" };
nonVisualGroupShapeProperties1.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties = new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties();
nonVisualGroupShapeProperties1.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();

GroupShapeProperties groupShapeProperties1 = shapeTree1.AppendChild(new GroupShapeProperties());
TransformGroup transformGroup1 = new TransformGroup();

transformGroup1.Offset = new Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
transformGroup1.Extents = new Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L };
transformGroup1.ChildOffset = new ChildOffset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
transformGroup1.ChildExtents = new ChildExtents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L };

groupShapeProperties1.Append(transformGroup1);

A.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties1 = new A.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties();
nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties1.NonVisualDrawingProperties = new A.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1, Name = "Chart" };
nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties1.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties = new A.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();

Transform transform1 = new Transform();
transform1.Offset = new Offset() { X = 2811110L, Y = 1000000L };
transform1.Extents = new Extents() { Cx = 6000000L, Cy = 5086100L };

Graphic graphic1 = new Graphic();
GraphicData graphicData1 = new GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" };

C.ChartReference chartReference1 = new C.ChartReference() { Id = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) };
chartReference1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
chartReference1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

graphicData1.Append(chartReference1);
graphic1.Append(graphicData1);

graphicFrame1.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties1);
graphicFrame1.Append(transform1);
graphicFrame1.Append(graphic1);

// Save the slide
slidePart.Slide.Save();

//////Add chart to slide
//ExternalData externalData = new ExternalData() { Id = "rId3" };
ExternalData externalData = new ExternalData() { Id = chartReference1.Id };
//ExternalData externalData = new ExternalData() { Id = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) };

AutoUpdate autoUpdate = new AutoUpdate() { Val = true };
externalData.Append(autoUpdate);

byte[] excelData = CreateExcelFileWithOpenXml(students);
string base64String = ConvertToBase64String(excelData);

EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart1 = chartPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "rId3");
//EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart1 = chartPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", slidePart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart));

GenerateEmbeddedPackagePartContent(embeddedPackagePart1, base64String);

//EmbeddingMethod(chartPart, headers, students);

chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(externalData);
chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
slidePart.Slide.Save();
presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
}

static void GenerateEmbeddedPackagePartContent(EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart1, string base64String)
{
    System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(base64String);
    embeddedPackagePart1.FeedData(data);
    data.Close();
}

static System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
{
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
}

static string ConvertToBase64String(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
}
static byte[] CreateExcelFileWithOpenXml(List<Student> students)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Get the sheetData cell table.
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        // Add header row.
        Row headerRow = new Row();
        headerRow.Append(
            new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue("Name"), DataType = CellValues.String },
            new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue("Values 1"), DataType = CellValues.String },
            new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue("Values 2"), DataType = CellValues.String },
            new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue("Values 3"), DataType = CellValues.String }
        );
        sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

        // Add student rows.
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            Row row = new Row();
            row.Append(
                new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(student.Name), DataType = CellValues.String },
                new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(student.Values[0].ToString()), DataType = CellValues.Number },
                new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(student.Values[1].ToString()), DataType = CellValues.Number },
                new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(student.Values[2].ToString()), DataType = CellValues.Number }
            );
            sheetData.AppendChild(row);
        }

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
    }
    return memStream.ToArray();
}
}
string GetExcelColumnName(int columnIndex)
{
const string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string columnName = "";

while (columnIndex > 0)
{
    columnIndex--;
    columnName = letters[columnIndex % 26] + columnName;
    columnIndex /= 26;
}

return columnName;
}

string GetColorHex(int index)
{
string[] colors = { "2751A5", "009DD9", "FF7D7D" };
return colors[index % colors.Length];
}
public class Student
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<int> Values { get; set; }

public Student(string name, List<int> values)
{
    Name = name;
    Values = values;
}
}

This is the code I am experimenting on. If I use namespace DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing for GraphicFrame, then there is no error but no chart is there. On the contrary, if I use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation for GraphicFrame, I get the chart but ppt is corrupted. So want your expertise for solving this issue.
I have tried to repair the file and compare it with the corrupted ppt file in Open XML SDK Productivity Tool but could not understand what changes are required.

I suggest reducing the code to the minimal amount to insert the chart and cause the corruption. Then insert the chart manually in another empty file. Then compare the openxml of each.

I tried that and the error starts arriving after I use the graphicframe code with the namespace in the program. So maybe someone can point out what to use and what to omit from the code to get the answer. Thanks for giving your advice.
